# HTC keeps losing connection to adb

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, adb, htc-android

I'm having issues with the adb connection to my HTC One S. Sometimes it connects just fine but after a couple of minutes or even seconds it loses connection and appears as offline. When this happens I unplug it and plug it back in, and then sometimes it doesnt show up in the devices list at all (or it takes way too long?). So I do it again, until it gets connected again, which may take a couple of tries. I've tried different cables, different USB ports, but they all work on my HTC Desire S while they all give said issues to my HTC One S. I've searched SO but haven't found a post which describes the exact same symptoms.

I'm getting pretty tired of this issue. Is there anyone who knows what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your htc driver and your device. Simpliest solution would be using AVD.

Comment: I've installed the latest version of HTC Sync Manager, is that what you meant? I'm not sure if theres other drivers for HTC. The issue still persists. My phone shows there are no updates available.